# flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer >=1.0.4 is forbidden

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I'm installing 2 packages: rxdart and flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer

```
rxdart: ^0.23.1
flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.7
```

but flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer >=1.0.4 is forbidden.

and this is error message:

```
Because flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer >=1.0.4 depends on rxdart ^0.21.0 and flutterattendancesystem depends on rxdart ^0.23.1, flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer >=1.0.4 is forbidden.

So, because flutterattendancesystem depends on flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer ^1.0.7, version solving failed.
pub upgrade failed (1; So, because flutterattendancesystem dep
ends on flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer ^1.0.7, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: What environment is this in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this thread https://github.com/CrossPT/flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer/issues/59

This repo is not maintained properly,
You can use a different package for pdf viewer.

or for a temporary fix do a following

Manually edit the `pubspec.yaml` in `flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer-1.0.7` folder in `.pub-cache` and set `rxdart: ^0.21.0` to `rxdart: ^0.23.1`.

In `flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer-1.07/lib/src/document.dart` at line no: `89`, changed `Observable` to `Stream`.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage from using rxdart: ^0.23.1 over the latest 0.24.0?  How, typically, would this affect functionality?